# SQLAlchemy MSSQL-IIF

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, iif

I could not find anything specific about this, but does SQL-Alchemy support the [MSSQL-IIF function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)?

Inside the docs I could not find any info for this and I guess I have to use the case-when block or a simple if instead?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that SQLAlchemy does not support IIF for SqlServer. The function is equal to the IF Function in MySQL but SqlAlchemy does not recognize this difference. Instead a case when then block can be used as an alternative to *func.IF*.